# What do Mohawks and scaffolding mean in this line from Annie Dillard’s Holy the Firm?

Tags: meaning, annie-dillard, holy-the-firm

What does this line mean from Annie Dillard’s *Holy the Firm*?

> In the high churches they saunter through the liturgy like Mohawks along a strand of scaffolding who have long since forgotten their danger.

I don’t understand how the word Mohawks is being used, nor scaffolding. I know what these words mean separately but I just don’t understand this sentiment. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

*Scaffolding* and *Mohawks* mean just what they mean separately; it's a piece of what used to be common knowledge that you're missing.

In the twentieth Century, Mohawk Indians were commonly employed as construction workers on high-rise buildings in New York City ... they were supposedly surefooted and not afraid of heights.

See the 1970s documentary [High Steel](https://bangshift.com/bangshiftxl/documentary-about-mohawks-building-manhattan-sky-scrapers/#:%7E:text=The%20year%20was%201916%20and%20the%20event%20was,literally%20build%20New%20York%20from%20the%20ground%20up.) and [this blog post](http://www.whitewolfpack.com/2012/09/the-mohawks-who-built-manhattan-photos.html).

Comment: See [Freilich (1958)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40453276).